# Category/label in fetch_20newsgroups dataset sklearn

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, k-means

I 'm studying clustering topic follow scikit-learn [example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/text/plot_document_clustering.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-text-plot-document-clustering-py):

I don't understand what is the different between 'category' and 'label'.

In this case the dataset is given from download:

```
dataset = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='all', categories=categories,
                             shuffle=True, random_state=42)
```

but i don't understand why write this category

```
categories = [
'alt.atheism',
'talk.religion.misc',
'comp.graphics',
'sci.space',
```

In the example, it is mentioned as "take from training set", but where is the train set?

```
labels = dataset.target
```

I don't understand why we need categories and labels seperately.

By the way, I found the resource of this dataset [here](http://qwone.com/~jason/20Newsgroups/) and seems that itis divided into

- train.data
- train.label
- train.map
- test.data
- test.label
- test.map

so i think when write

```
dataset.data
```

It gives a sparse matrix).

So my question is, how to choose category and label? if I dont have a dataset like in this example, I need to choose arbitrarily?

Sorry for my question, but i try to understand this example in right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the categories are specified to filter the records from the original dataset. let us say we get 1200 articles only using the filter. By default, the original dataset has 20 categories. If we don't specify the categories, it will pull all articles of all categories into the dataset.

```
'alt.atheism',
'talk.religion.misc',
'comp.graphics',
'sci.space',
```

whereas dataset.target is used to get the labels for each article from the dataset, which we had filtered in the previous step.

```
labels = dataset.target
```

labels will be of size 1200 and each value represent which category each article belongs to.

You only to get choose the categories. Labels are already present for each article, so we dont have to role to play here.

`dataset.target_names` would give the mapping between labels and categories, meaning 0,1,2 in the labels mean what category.

Comment: First all thanks for you clarification. So the category is an vantage to filter the data? in this case the filter is reported here "dataset = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='all', categories=categories,
                             shuffle=True, random_state=42) "... In this case take just the  useful dataset elements, right? This is usuful to make light a data? Can be done without this category?

Comment: yes, it helps to make the data light. I would not say we are removing the non-useful elements from the dataset by this step, we are just ignoring the other categories.

Comment: I tryed to print label too and the output is just [1 0 1 ... 0 0 1] and i don't understand how this can be used in other dataset. I thought it was a series of elements, like a list of names.

Comment: dataset.target_names[0] or dataset.target_names[1] would give the corresponding  category names.

Comment: i see well and the vector is based with element from 0 to 3 that as you say indicate the category. This vector is costructed before ?

Comment: once you specify the categories, these labels would be created. Before that it would be mapped with respect to all 20 categories